# Speed issue with multiple php objects in one GLOBAL array

Tags: php, class, multidimensional-array, global

My website is slow and sometimes after about 1 or 2 minuets, it gives "Internal Sever Error 500".
I believe because I have put objects in ONE Global array is causing the issue. Here is what I have:
I have multiple objects of php classes

```
$a = new HeaderPrint();
$b = new SpFunctions();
$c = new Calculations();
```

and I don't want to declare **EACH of them** as them as global inside function of classes. 
I have done this:

```
$MYCODE['OBa']=$a;
$MYCODE['OBb']=$b;
$MYCODE['OBc']=$c;
```

and this is how I use them in another class:

```
class TaxCalc{
     function interst($amount){
             global $MYCODE;

           $MYCODE['OBc']->someFunction();
     ....
     ....
     }
 }
```

this way I have only ONE variable **$MYCODE** array to  declare as global. 
It is working but may be this or something else is slowing the website down.

**please help me:**

1-Anything wrong with this?

2-If this is not good, as I have used the **$MYCODE** inside 100s of other functions what to do to fix this issue?

Comment: Pass them as argument to the function

Comment: It seems for me that you could use static methods here. It's just a bunch of utility classes with utility functions, isn't it?

Comment: If you're using safari, right-click and go to inspect element. Then click the timelines button in the top right and refresh the page. The timelines tool will help you figure out what is slowing down the website.

Comment: @Royal Bg I don't know the meaning of "static methods" and "utility classes" . the objects are of classes that either read database to print on screen, update record or do calculations.

Comment: @Developer_ACE the problem is the page sometimes doesn't load to see what is the problem. is what I do correct?

Comment: @Rizier123 I have used the $MYCODE array 100s of places, very hard to modify all functions.

Comment: @user2635979 do you have access to your server logs? If you do, refresh the page a few times. Now navigate to your server's logs and look for a file that is named something like `scripts.log`. Now download that log file and open it, at the bottom should be a few lines describing any script errors that occurred that prevented the page from loading. please post your log file here if you need help reading it.

Comment: Don't go with static methods: If you want to use this object with another one and mock it out, it's going to be a nightmare for unit testing because you can't mock out objects with static methods any more. Just make them instance methods. It's 2015. Nobody uses statics any more.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days waiting I could not wait longer to find some descent solution.
So here is what I did and the website is running very fast.
Instead of this:

**global $MYCODE;**
I used **global $a, $b, $c ....**
and I have 23 objects so I did it that way.